# I'm getting this error when i'm trying to add days Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addDays(Decimal) from the type Date

Tags: apex, datetime, date

```
if(application.genesis__Lending_Product__r.Name=='Restructured Term Loan')
{
    loanAccount.loan__Accrual_Start_Date__c= systemDate.addDays(application.Deferred_Payment__c*7);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numeric fields in Salesforce are not stored as `Integer`. If you want to pull a field value and save it as an integer, you have a few different options. One way to do it would look like:

```
Integer dayCount = 7 * Integer.valueOf(application.Deferred_Payment__c);
systemDate.addDays(dayCount);
```